# Как использовать метод pack?

Tags: java, swing

Пишут, что метод pack класса Window очень полезный. Что он якобы устанавливает оптимальный размер для диалоговых окон. Но у меня после вызова метода pack окно становится размером ноль на ноль. Что делать? Когда вообще полезно использовать pack, а когда не стоит?

Comment: У вас, наверное, ни одного компонента нет? Вот pack() и решил, что раз нечего показывать, то и окно можно уменьшить.

Comment: Нет, есть компоненты.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

krivenko, метод pack() устанавливает такой минимальный размер контейнера, который достаточен для отображения всех компонентов. Если метод у вас работает иначе, значит вы делаете что-то неверно.

А вот мой вам совет: по вопросам КАК что-то работает смотрите [API Specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).
Такие сайты как этот существуют для того, чтобы вы знали, ЧТО использовать и ГДЕ.

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой.
В итоге, выяснил метод pack() должен вызываться после добавления всех элементов, ибо, при расчёте размера окна, он учитывает только ранее добавленные элементы а элементы добавленные позднее в расчёт не идут.

Возможно есть ещё какие-то причины по которым метод может работать не верно, но у меня после исправления этой ошибки всё заработало как надо.